# how can i check validation values before sumbitting using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

i have this code   that i wrote to build regular form of registration , with the terms i want on each label ,but some how i can't get the right answers

```js
function validateForm() {
 var flag = true;
 var name1 = document.forms["myForm"]["full name"].value;
 var password1 = document.forms["myForm"]["password"].value;
 var repassword1 = document.forms["myForm"]["passwordrepeat"].value;

 if (name1 == null || name1 == "" || name1.value.matchs(/^[A-Za-z]+$/)) {
  document.getElementById("nameError").style = "color:red;"
  document.getElementById("nameError").innerHTML = "please enter name,  with letters only!";
  flag = false;
 }
 if (password1 == null || password1 == "" || !/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$ /.test(password1))
 {
  document.getElementById("passError").style = "color:red;"
  document.getElementById("passError").innerHTML = "please enter the passwords with values A - Z and 0 - 9";
  flag = false;
 }
 if (repassword1 == null || repassword1 == "" ||
  repassword1.value != password1.value) {
  document.getElementById("passwordrepeatError").style = "color:red;"
  document.getElementById("passwordrepeatError").innerHTML = "please enter the passwords matchs!";
  flag = false;
 }

 if (flag == false)
  return false;
 else {
  window.alert("you've been registed successfully !");
 }
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
 full name :
 <input type="text" name="full name"><label id=nameError></label>
 <br> password :
 <input type="password" name="password"><label id=passError></label>
 <br> re-password :
 <input type="password" name="passwordrepeat"><label id=passwordrepeatError></label>
 <br><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

it works when all fields are empty like this<:
   [image]

but i fill the labels and click sumbit , all the values deleted and don't get the msgs , what did i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
name1.value.matchs(/^[A-Za-z]+$/))
```

This line should be changed to the following as match is spelled incorrectly and the variable already contains the value. You have to add the negation symbol to the start because you only want to display the error if the name does not match your regex.

```
!name1.match(/^[A-Za-z]+$/)
```

You need to remove the space between the last two symbols from this regex too:

```
!/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$ /
```